# Credential leaking while unconscious

Tags: physical, credentials, secret-sharing

Bear with me here, because this admittedly sounds nutty, but I had a dream last night in which I distinctly recall (accurately) typing the master password for my password manager into a (dream) computer. To my horror, the password displayed in cleartext in my dream (it was a true nightmare).

Upon waking, I got to thinking, "what sort of human vulnerabilities do we have while unconscious or dreaming?" What if I spoke my master password out loud while sleeping? Are there any other unconscious ways in which we could disclose secrets that only we are privy to?

(Maybe this is better suited for the biology stackexchange? I figured I'd ask here first since the heart of the question is really regarding security)

Comment: General solution would be to not know your passwords and using other factors to authenticate. (I know this doesn't answer your question).

Comment: In my opinion this question is off-topic. Similar questions would be about extracting information while on drugs, blackmailing or threatening or seducing somebody to get secrets etc.

Comment: I voted as opinion-based as there is no public scientific research on this for good reasons. This borders „how can I control what people dream of“. While answers might have security implications, the heart of the question does not. I don’t think biology would be a good SE, either.

Comment: I think it's on-topic, at least, since questions relating to password storage in non-declarative memory are on-topic. The answer I would have given, anyway, would be simply that it depends on the individual, and some people are more prone to saying things in their sleep that they'd rather remain private.